# If my dataframe has no NaNs why is lasso model not running?

Tags: python, lasso-regression

I am running a model.fit it was running perfectly and I have no clue what I did that now is not running. Little background I made a dataframe and added values to all the NaNs in the columns. then created my predictor and target and the ran the lasso model. When I ran the lasso model is giving me the Value error of Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
also I double checked that my columns don't have NaN values by running final_data.isna().sum() and saw that all the columns had a return of 0

```
def build_and_fit_lasso_model(X, y):
    """Creates and returns a LASSO model that is fitted to the values of the
    given predictor and target X, and y.
    """
    model = LassoLarsCV(cv=10, precompute = False)  
    model = model.fit(X_train.values, y_train.values)
    return model # implement this function
```

Then when I run this is giving me the error

```
lasso_model = build_and_fit_lasso_model(X_train, y_train)
lasso_model
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example is what we all would like...

Answer (score 0):

In my data frame had NaNs and my function did not catch them properly. Problem resolved.